# Can I run weblogic on two different port?

Tags: java, weblogic, clone

I am a newbie to weblogic. I have two wars(includes same code with feature1 and feature2) with the same context.I cannot merge the code as they are planned for different releases.

I want to test them simultaneously.I have an idea about JBoss cloning.In Jboss,I can run 2 wars simultaneously on different ports.

Can I do the same in weblogic? If yes,then how?

And there is one more way, that I can do with change of context in weblogic.xml.That way I can deploy two wars with different context.

Comment: You can create and start 2 managed servers on the same host listenting two differents ports. Each web app is deployed on its own managed server. You can also use network chanels if you only want to use a single managed server

Answer (score 4):

"A WebLogic Server domain always has exactly one administration server. This special instance of WebLogic Server is responsible for the configuration of the entire domain. Other servers in the domain are called managed servers, and they are typically the servers on which you run your applications. A domain can contain any number of managed servers." - From Oracle Docs

So, you can achieve this creating 2 managed servers in your domain, as they will run independently from each other. You will need to create another managed server and configure everything for this new instance (such as Data Sources and other services)

You can find how to configure a managed server on Oracle Docs attached (the tutorial is a bit long to put down in images here). I've been using these for years on my development environment and it works just fine.
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/12_1_3/02/configmanaged.html

To deploy your application to a managed server you can follow the steps below:

1. Deploying an application is a change to the domain's configuration, so it must first be locked. In the Change Center, click the Lock & Edit button.
2. Under Domain Structure, click Deployments.
3. On the right, under Deployments, click the Install button.
4. Find the Current Location field. Use the links to browse to the location in which you can find your desired .war file
5. On the next screen, ensure that Install this deployment as an application is selected.
6. On the next screen, select your new managed server and click next
7. On the next screen, keep all the default values and click Next.
8. On the next screen, select No, I will review the configuration later. Then click Finish.
9. Notice the messages that the deployment was installed, but changes must be activated. Also notice the benefits application listed in the Deployments table.
10. In the Change Center click the Activate Changes button.